# why I can't calculate the right CRC?

Tags: plc, modbus, crc16

Recently I'm writing a simple program to download g-code to a PLC device ,which is based on Modbus RTU.But I can't figure which CRC code is the right one.
Address is "02",function code is"0x7A",g-code string (hex) is "4E303020473030205831302E30205931302E300D"(ascii mode of "N00 G00 X10.0 Y10.0(Enter)").
The PLC Manual shows that CRC code is "578E",but almost softwares shows "42FD".How can I calculate the right one?

manual photo:
https://mmbiz.qlogo.cn/mmbiz/icVMts8g1VicuveK36HJzInQW3cicVBTDINBeNYyZrMSSbO6dlZ8DMf258ESTibIansmhhEl7icnhuy4Dv9KeQnfkow/0?wx_fmt=png

software photo:
https://mmbiz.qlogo.cn/mmbiz/icVMts8g1VicuveK36HJzInQW3cicVBTDINtHs6My1hs4kySSjsicVNNQU0gH6AHiaklLTZzS2jj9mu7xqjBReJoA4g/0?wx_fmt=png

Comment: I suggest that you do a search for "modbus crc", which will give code examples. [Also, as many of us here on Stack Overflow are not very good with languages other than English, it might have been helpful if you had given the English translation of those messages.]

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, thank you! In fact, I am not very good at English…